# Return a spilled range whose height is same as a given table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet as follows. In Column C, there is a table `Table5` whose height may change. In Column E, my colleague is supposed to enter some numbers, but their height is inferior or equal than the height of `Table5`. In Column F, there is a formula to calculate the multiplication.

The formula in Column F returns correct values, but one problem is that it exceeds the height of `Table5`.

So, I'm looking for a dynamic array formula (e.g., in Column G), to return the correct values as Column F, but the height of the spilled range should be same as `Table5`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Why are the Input and Output ranges not simply part of Table5?

Comment: Good point too. It should simply be part of the data in the 1st place.

Comment: Because the input part is supposed to be entered by another person. I would prefer to separate it from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just wrap it in `IFERROR()`:

```
=IFERROR(E4:E20*Table5[Coefficient],"")
```

If that is not an option for you, just slice the right amount of rows from the spilled array using `INDEX()`, assuming at least a single row of data:

```
=INDEX(E4:E20*Table5[Coefficient],SEQUENCE(COUNT(Table5[Coefficient])))
```

Or `FILTER()` out the errors:

```
=FILTER(E4:E20*Table5[Coefficient],ISNUMBER(E4:E20*Table5[Coefficient]))
```

---

If you don't even want to mention the range in column E, you could use a volatile `OFFSET()`:

```
=Table5[Coefficient]*OFFSET(Table5[Coefficient],,2)
```

---

If you just want to mention only `E4`, then use `INDEX()`:

```
=Table5[Coefficient]*E4:INDEX(E:E,COUNT(Table5[Coefficient])+3)
```

Comment: Thank you. The second one is better. But I would prefer not to mention or use `E4:E20`, is it possible?

Comment: See the edit. However, use it sparsely, `OFFSET()` is volatile and will recalculate upon almost any action in Excel.

Comment: Is it possible not to use OFFSET? I would prefer not to mention `E4:E20`, but using `E4` is OK.

Comment: @SoftTimur, Why are you not clear about what you need in your actual question?

Comment: Or at least put the input values in a table as well, that way there's no reference to a worksheet column (although I fail to see why that is such an issue): `=INDEX(Table5[Coefficient]*InputTable[Input],SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table5[Coefficient])))`